# In airflow, can I create the pool inside the DAG if it does not exists?

Tags: airflow

I have a dag that triggers an external DAG using `TriggerDagOperator`. The trigger DAG queries a database and based on a type ID, it will trigger the associated external DAG along with the parameters needed for the external DAG. I would want to pass a pool name as part of these parameters and just wondering if I can create the pool in the (external) DAG if it does not exists.

Comment: Check this out if it helps
https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-pools/

Comment: That is just straightforward use of pool which we are already using. I am looking for dynamically creating a pool inside DAG.

Comment: Is this something that you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426489/create-dynamic-pool-in-airflow

Comment: But the problem is pool cannot be templated (`pool="{{dag_run.conf['pool_name']}}"`).  So cannot really create the pool because cannot access the conf value.